# How do I save the selected photos from iPhone Photo Library into the document directory?

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, swift4.1

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 "The file “IMG_0125.PNG”
>   couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it."
>   UserInfo={NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0125.PNG,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x1c045d130 Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1
>   "Operation not permitted"}}

I am getting above error while using below code

```
do{
    try filemanager.copyItem(at: sourceURL, to: dirConPath1)
}catch let error as NSError{
    print(error.debugDescription)
}
```

Also I have added:

```
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>want access of photos</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
    <string>photos save description.</string>
```

into the `info.plist`

I am using Swift 4.1 and Xcode 9.3.1.

Comment: you need to store image in document directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to save image in local directory put this method in your file and just call with your image and image name ...

```
func saveImageToDocumentLocal(name:String,image:UIImage)  {
                let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
                let random = arc4random()
                let fileURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("\(name)\(random)")
                if let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5),
                        !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path) {
                        do {
                            try data.write(to: fileURL)
                            print("file saved")
                            print(fileURL.path)

                        } catch {
                            print("error saving file:", error)
                        }
                }else{
            }
        }
```